# CSS animation forwards is preventing css transitions

Tags: css, transition

I am setting my CSS animation type to `forwards` so that the finished frame of the animation is the default state when finished.

But now, the transition that animates the same property (`transform`) is not working anymore...

I have to use `forwards` because otherwise the opacity resets to 0 after animating.

How can I enable a transition as soon as an animation has finished? I am looking for a CSS-only option without javascript.

CSS

```
album {
    opacity: 0;
    animation:movein 0.6s forwards;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

album:hover {
    transform:scale(1.05);                       // this doesn't work
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 45px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);    // this works
}

@keyframes movein {
  from {
    opacity:0;
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }

  to {
    opacity:1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

album:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 0.2s;       // delay keeps opacity 0 for a while
}
album:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 0.4s;       // delay keeps opacity 0 for a while
}
```

Comment: Mind adding your HTML too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to split up your animation. Only the fadein animation has animation forwards.

```
album {
    opacity: 0;
    animation:movein 0.6s, fadein 0.6s forwards;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes movein {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity:0;
  }
  to {
    opacity:1;
  }
```

}